# Btrfs Undelete File

Tags: file-recovery, btrfs

I would like to undelete a large file I deleted using the rm -r command on the directory it was located in. The file was on a 1TB usb external harddisk. Nothing was written to the disk after the file was deleted, I simply unmounted and realised my mistake. I'm fairly sure I know the name of the file, although it would be handy to be able to see a list of previous files in case there was another deleted by mistake.

I've seen this question:
[How to undelete files on btrfs partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/415132/how-to-undelete-files-on-btrfs-partition)

I tried what was suggested there but had no luck:

```
./btrfs-undelete /dev/sdb1 mydir/file.name
Searching roots... found 0 roots.
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/btrfs-undelete.19720': No such file or directory
Didn't find 'mydir/file.name'
```

I am therefore stumped. Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Comment: Looking at the btrfs-undelete script it actually has some odd stuff in it: _/find-root /dev/mapper/queen-home_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I did it.

I first did

```
btrfs-find-root /dev/sdb1
```

Which gave me a large list. The one that I was interested in was:

```
Well block 65626112 seems great, but generation doesn't match, have=1000, want=1001
```

So now I mounted another hard disk as I was short of space. Then I did:

```
btrfs restore -t 65626112 /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

Using the 65626112 which I had found from the previous command. It is now restoring the files from the btrfs filesystem to /media/usb and I can copy any I want and delete the rest. If I still don't find the file I am after I can use the next block from the list until I do.

Comment: I should mention it is restoring everything that was on the drive at that time. So plenty of space is needed.

Comment: There's a new --dry-run option, use it with -v to see the list of files that would be restored.